# Shows site under construction but comes up after I login to admin

Tags: admin

I have a strange issue happening with a new site. It keeps going down and shows under construction, but after I login to WP admin, the site comes back up! Any suggestions as to what might be going on here? Thanks!

Comment: There is not really enough information here to answer the question. Please add [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress), disable your plugins and switch to a default theme. Then [edit] the question with information gained from those tests.

Answer (score 1):

That's probably because the site is visible for admin but not for public. This might be due to a maintenance plugin or a code in functions.php or in htaccess.

This could also be due to a cache issue. In this case try to delete the cache.